# Azure pipeline mapping I want to add one static field in json while csv import

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

This is input I want to assign a static value to username so that when this csv will load that static value will be inserted in destination

```
{
        "name": "Input_dat",
        "properties": {
            "structure": [
                {
                    "name": "ServerName",
                    "type": "String"
                },
                {
                    "name": "DTVer",
                    "type": "Double"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Ver",
                    "type": "Double"
                },
                {
                    "name": "UserName",
                    "type": "String"
                }
            ],
            "published": false,
            "type": "AzureBlob",
            "linkedServiceName": "Source-AzureBlob",
            "typeProperties": {
                "folderPath": "foldwr/folder1/Import/",
                "format": {
                    "type": "TextFormat",
                    "rowDelimiter": "\n",
                    "columnDelimiter": "\u0001"
                }
            },
            "availability": {
                "frequency": "Day",
                "interval": 1
            },
            "external": true,
            "policy": {}
        }
    }
```

E.g username="sqladlin"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this if your souce is a blob storage. Maybe add the field in the csv before its ingested by data factory, or after.

If you really want to do this with data factory, I think the only option is to go for a custom activity.

Hope this helped!